Index value of Repeat Zone doesn't increase automatically
The Store Named Attribute face_no should be 0, 1, 2, ... till 9. But I only got 9 for all faces. Is there anything I did wrong?


Here is my final solution without Repeated Zone node.

To add to Gordon Brinkmann's answer, the diamond shape of the idx value means every face can have its own value. But the dot inside the diamond means you are giving the same value to all faces. So as Gordon said, you give everything a value of 1, then everything a value of 2, ... until 9. So you erase everything at each step.

Yes, there is something you are doing wrong. In the Store Named Attribute node you have selected to store the value "Idx" as attribute "face_no" on faces. But you are not making any Selection which face should store which value. So on each iteration, the current value is stored on all faces, overwriting the previous value.
Now what selection you want to make is up to you. For example, take a Compare node and check where Index is equal to "Idx" like below:

But I guess (I hope) you want to do something more complex than this, because a trivial task like writing the index number of each face into an attribute on that face can be done completely without Repeat Zone and Selection etc. Actually if you needed the index of a face you could simply read it directly, no need for attributes at all. But just in case you insist on having it as attribute:

Of course if you do not want the pure index but want to do some math operations on the index value like adding to it or multiplying etc., you would need an attribute.
But there is another way. The attribute is especially needed if you want to store values on faces, edges etc. and maybe not integers, but floats, vectors and other types. But if you want to strictly store integers and only on vertices, you could use the Set ID node:

The Set ID node stores integers on vertices. By default, the Index node and the ID node always read the index of an element. However, unless you have set special ID values, in this case the Index will still provide the index of vertices, but the ID node will now give the ID values stored on the vertices.

Thanks a lot. That's the root cause. (I am just a newbie to Blender.)

@belcon I added something at the end.

Yes. You are correct. I want to put tiles on the top of the roof via geometry nodes. Step (1): Find out all roofs based on the normals; Step (2) According to the length of each roofs and base tile, put tiles on the roof lines by lines. Just my start-up project to get familiar with geometry nodes.

@belcon I added another thing to add a little bit for the overview.

Great. Gordon. I think you are correct. Repeat Zone is not necessary here.
